# Connaissez vous une Onomastique en ligne?

Tags: étymologie, noms

Salut mes amis tricolores !

J'ai besoin d'un dictionnaire en ligne pour rechercher l'étymologie des noms de famille à la façon du *Digitales Familienamenwörterbuch Deutschlands* (DFD, en Allemagne), par exemple.

On peut utiliser le Trésor de la Langue Française (TLFi), Französisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch (FEW, en Allemagne), Dictionnaire Étymologique Roman (DERom), Romanisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch (REW, en Allemagne), tous en ligne, pour ce qui est des noms communs, mais ces offres excluent les noms propres.

Où trouver des références onomastiques recouvrant les patronymes français, y a-t-il une norme académique avec laquelle il faut compter ?

<sub>This is auto-translated back and forth. I'd rather write: “Où-est un onomasticon du France, est-ce qu'il y a standard academique, reliable avec ...” nonsense. It's almost funny how they make a better question than I could.</sub>

<sub>In short, please give your two sentences of critique if you have a link to make an answer.</sub>

Pour donner un exemple, le nom de *Walt Disney* est lié à *d'Isigny*. J'ai besoin d'une source pour ça.

Comment: There are a few things on the web, e.g. [Dictionnaire des noms de famille](https://jeantosti.com/noms/a.html), on [geanet](https://www.geneanet.org/nom-de-famille/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bonjour. Il y a le travail de Jean Tosti, [Dictionnaire des noms de famille](https://jeantosti.com/noms/a.html), qui contient pas mal de noms de France et est accessible en ligne. Il y a également le *Dictionnaire étymologique des noms de famille et prénoms de France* de Albert Dauzat, mais je ne sais pas s’il existe une version en ligne.